# Migración de una página en WordPress y sincronización de cambios

Tags: wordpress, data, migration

He investigado un poco sobre la migración de datos y he encontrado que es posible hacerla mediante un plugin llamado "All-in-One Wp Migration", pero sobre la sincronización de cambios, no especifica si es posible. Esa es mi duda, quisiera saber si es posible que el contenido de una página A se pueda migrar a la página B (un dominio distinto), y que luego de esta migración, todos los cambios que yo realice en la página A se vean reflejados en la página B. De antemano gracias.

Comment: Parece una pregunta basada en opiniones lo que generaría su cierre.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! o sea tu pregunta es como sincronizar dos sitios wordpress??

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a lo que quieres hacer. Cuando migras una página es porque piensas cambiar de dominio. Si lo que quieres es tener dos páginas sincronizadas es otro asunto.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios, efectivamente, el objetivo de buscar esta sincronización era relacionar un sitio de prueba con uno de producción, aún estoy aprendiendo Wordpress así que sus respuestas me ayudan mucho. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Claro que es posible, pero no deberías centrate solo en los plugins, lo ideal es que captes la esencia del asunto y lo comprendas.

Básicamente WordPress son tres cosas:

- Los archivos que componen WordPress como tal y los plugins que añades
- Los archivos que tú subes a WordPress (imágenes, documentos, etc...)
- La base de datos de WordPress

Si coges esas tres cosas y te las llevas a otro sitio, tendrás tu instalación funcionando perfectamente. Solo hay que hacer algunos ajustes.

**Mover los archivos** es muy sencillo, te bajas toda tu instalación de WordPress y la mueves al sitio nuevo.

**Mover la base de datos** también es relativamente simple, si usas phpMyAdmin puedes usar la herramienta para exportar la base de datos y luego importarla en el otro sitio. Es probable que tu base de datos tenga un nombre, usuario y clave distintos en el nuevo sitio. Estos cambios tienes que reflejarlos en el archivo *wp-config.php* de tu instalación de WordPress.

Si lo estás moviendo a una URL distinta, tienes que colocar la nueva URL en el registro correspondiente en la tabla *wp_options* (suponiendo que tu instalación usa el prefijo *wp_*).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Busca los registros con option_name siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y actualiza la URL del sitio.

**Para mantener los datos sincronizados** tendrás que repetir el proceso o buscar una solución que lo realice de manera automática para ti, pero tu problema en este caso se reduce a:

- Mantener sincronizada la base de datos
- Mantener sincronizado el directorio */wp-content/* *(aquí es donde viven las plantillas, plugins y medios que subes al sitio)*
- Mantener actualizado WordPress a la última versión

De todas formas, buscando por el repositorio oficial de plugins, he encontrado este: [WPSiteSync](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wpsitesynccontent/)

Comment: No tiene sentido tener sitios sincronizados. Si son dominios públicos por ejemplo, serán penalizados a nivel de SEO por contenido duplicado. La migración tendría sentido en el caso de de querer cambiar de dominio. Esa idea de sitios sincronizados no queda muy clara en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo un caso útil que le veo es tener sincronizada una versión local con una online. Puedes trabajar en local sin tener acceso a internet y cuando tengas acceso sincronizar todos los cambios a la versión online. Otro caso es tener una instalación en un servidor B y tener el acceso público bloqueado, pero usarlo como copia de seguridad. Es verdad que hay formas mejores de hacerlo pero bueno, ahí está ;)